# Функция в C++ не видит динамический массив

Tags: c++, рекурсия, динамические-массивы

Программа находит все перестановки n элементов. В функции perm() в условии пишет, что идентификатор chosen не определен. Объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема и как ее решить.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int n;
void perm();
vector<int> permutation;

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    bool *chosen = new bool[n+1];
    perm();
    delete[] chosen;

}

void perm()
{
    if (permutation.size() == n) {
        for (auto c : permutation) {
            cout << c << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";

    }else {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (chosen[i]) continue;
            chosen[i] = true;
            permutation.push_back(i);
            perm();
            chosen[i] = false;
            permutation.pop_back();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: функцию perm с аргументами perm(int* chosen) сделайте т.к область видимости *chosen только функция main

Comment: @Ecko,  не совсем понял, почему нужно написать именно _int*_ chosen  и какой аргумент давать функции при ее вызове?

Comment: Вопрос вы тут пытаетесь сделать через рекурсию это обязательно? Так как число перестановок из 6 цифр это уже 6! = 720 а так как рекурсия выполняется через стек он очень быстро у вас переполнится

Comment: void perm(int* chosen) а в функции main perm(chosen)

Comment: @Ecko, perm(chosen) выдает ошибку, т.к. chosen - bool. 

А нельзя просто объявить chosen в другом месте, чтобы все работало и в perm() не надо было вставлять аргументы?

Comment: Был не внимателен замените int на bool

Comment: @Ecko, в таком случае программа ничего не выводит

Comment: Если вы не понимаете, почему в `perm` не видна переменная `chosen`, то: перестать пытаться писать код, читать книги по азам языка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int>v(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        v[i] = i + 1;
    do {
        for (const auto& item: v)
            cout << item << ' ';
        cout << endl;

    } while(next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выдает: идентификатор iota не определен

Comment: альгоритм iota  определен в  <numeric>

Answer (score 2):

Имя `chosen` видно только в функции `main`, потому что сущность с таким именем объявлена внутри нее. В другие функции, даже если они вызываются из `main`, имя `chosen` попасть не может. Его видимость ограничено `main`.

Для того чтобы `chosen` стало видно в функции `perm`, нужно его "поднять" в область видимости, общую для `main` и `perm`. В данном случае глобальную область видимости в которой уже находятся имена `n` и `permutation`.